# C# Insert directory structure into a rich text box on form

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
}
```

And I have a `RichTextBox`:

```
private void richTextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

How can I return / output the data from the method into the `RichTextBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the filenames, you can use Enumerable.Aggregate to turn them into a string and set that string as the text for the Rich Text Box:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox4.Text = 
        Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MyDir\")
                 .Aggregate("", (text, pathName) => 
                     text += String.Format("{0}\n", pathName))
                  );
}
```

Comment: Error 4 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\\GUI App\Form1.cs 218 72 GUI App

Comment: @Dan - I had already fixed the sample before you posted your comment. I didn't realize you were working with strings already.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(string path in filePaths) {
    richTextBox4.AppendText(path + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Error 2 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'AppendLine' and no extension method 'AppendLine' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\GUI App\Form1.cs 216 30 GUI App

Comment: @Dan: I fixed the code sample. I imagined that rtb provides the method `AppendLine` but in fact it does not

Comment: @Dan: feel free to mark the answer that you found the moust helpful as accepted (by pressing on a checkmark). Oh, and welcome to the site

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
richTextBox4.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filePaths);
```